# ipython notebook output from child process

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When using ipython notebook, the output of child processes spawned by `subprocess` never shows up in the notebook itself. For example, this cell

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['echo', 'hello'])
```

Only shows `0` as output, and the `hello` is printed on the terminal where ipython is launched.

Is there any configuration parameters I can tune such that the output of child processes show up in the notebook itself?

---

Actually custom python c extensions will also have their output swallowed. Is there any fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `check_output` if you want the output captured. `check_call` returns the exit code.

```
import subprocess
print subprocess.check_output(['echo', 'hello'])
```

Comment: The full output is captured after the command has finished when using `check_output`. The process I want to actually call is long running, and it writes to stdout and stderr a lot of logging information. I want to view these logging information during the execution, so `check_output` is not the way to go.

Comment: In Python3:

print(subprocess.check_output(['echo', 'hello']))

Answer (score 6):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen (['echo', 'hello'], stdout=PIPE)
out = p.communicate ()
print (out)
(b'hello\n', None)
```

You can also look at stderr, similarly

Answer (score 1):

From python3.5+

I feel that I should add a better answer. The `subprocess` module now supplies the `run` method which according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html):

`The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run() function for all use cases it can handle. For more advanced use cases, the underlying Popen interface can be used directly.`

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

result = run (['echo', 'hello'], stdout=PIPE)
print (result.returncode, result.stdout)

0 b'hello\n'
```